# autopurchase bot using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, bots

hey i was trying to built a bot that open a website searches a specific domain name if domain is available it should proceed to payment page or if not available retry after few seconds.
so far i have learnt this much only

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import chromedriver_binary

import random
import time
wd = wd.Chrome()
wd.implicitly_wait(10)

wd.get("https://mitsu.in/domain-registration/index.php")
```

website on which i want to try this bot https://mitsu.in/domain-registration/index.php

Comment: Welcome to SO - What is your concret question? Please improve your information.

Comment: What is the domain name that you want to search using Selenium ?.

Comment: Actually I was trying to create a bot that buys a domain name after it expires (tnrera.in) before any backorder service pick the domains

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.